# Count daily records and compare across multiple years

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

Hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as I not great with SQL and not been able to find what I need online.  I have tblRegister in which multiple records a day are created and now need to compare each day across multiple years.

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 1 |
| 2010-01-01 | 2 |
| 2010-01-01 | 3 |
| 2010-01-02 | 4 |
| 2010-01-03 | 5 |
| 2010-01-03 | 6 |
| ... and so on up to today | # |

I am trying to work out how to query the data so that I can compare each day of the year across multiple years (so can then review for spikes / troughs trends when graphed)

| date | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | ...2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 Jan | 3 | count(id) | count(id) | count(id) |
| 02 Jan | 1 | count(id) | count(id) | count(id) |
| 03 Jan | 2 | count(id) | count(id) | count(id) |
| ...for each dd MMM of the calendar year | count(id) | count(id) | count(id) | count(id) |

Hope someone might be able to assist.  Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

Comment: Check out `PIVOT`.

Comment: What does the Feb 29 row look like?

Comment: Also Management Studio isn't a database platform, it's just a client tool. `SELECT @@VERSION;` will be more useful

Comment: How many years do you have?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for replying.  Yeah I have been reading up on PIVOT but it needs to be dynamic to pick up the year going forward and I have been struggling with the SQL SELECT and no luck yet

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Thanks for posting.  Output of that = MS SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR)

Comment: @Charlieface Many thanks for looking.  I have from 2010 - today >33k rows

Comment: You should look into upgrading, SQL Server 2012 is years out of any kind of support.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I know, yes.  The IT department are working on that we've been told but no idea of timescale.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could build a dynamic `PIVOT` that takes into account all the years present in the table and builds out a column for each one.

```
-- pick an arbitrary leap year, like 2020
DECLARE @leapyear char(4)       = '2020', 
        @cols     nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @cols = STUFF
  ((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(YEAR(date))
    FROM dbo.[a table] 
    GROUP BY YEAR(date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(date)
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 
           1, 1, N'');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT date = CONVERT(char(6), 
    CONVERT(date, @ly + d), 106), ' + @cols + N' FROM 
(
  SELECT y = YEAR([date]), 
         d = RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), date, 112), 4), 
         c = COUNT(id)
  FROM dbo.[a table]
  GROUP BY YEAR([date]), RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8), date, 112), 4)
) AS x PIVOT (MAX(c) FOR y IN (' + @cols + N')) p 
ORDER BY d;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@ly char(4)', @leapyear;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OupRcARx) - makes an assumption of how you want to handle February 29th, which will only have values for certain years.